# Find directories not containing a specific directory

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, find

Been searching around for a bit and cannot find a solution for this one. I guess I'm looking for a leaf-directory by name. In this example I'd like to get a list of directories call 'modules' that do NOT have a subdirectory called module.

```
modules/package1/modules/spackage1
modules/package1/modules/spackage2
modules/package1/modules/spackage3/modules
modules/package1/modules/spackage3/modules/spackage1
modules/package2/modules/
```

The list I desire would contain

```
modules/package1/modules/spackage3/modules/
modules/package2/modules/
```

All the directories named module that do not have a subdirectory called module

I started with trying something this with no luck

```
find . -name modules \! -exec sh -c 'find -name modules' \;
```

-exec works on exit code, okay lets pass the count as exit code

```
find . -name modules -exec sh -c 'exit $(find {} -name modules|grep -n ""|tail -n1|cut -d: -f1)' \;
```

This should take the count of each subdirectory called modules and exit with it. No such love.

Comment: Could you clarify your example desired list, because `modules/package1/modules/spackage1/modules/` is not a directory you specified in your sample structure. Thanks.

Comment: Interestingly I've just notice that

`find . -name modules -exec sh -c 'exit 0' \;`

returns no results. Based on the manpage I would guess exit 0 would make it the same as if the -exec statement was not there.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes GNU `find`. Find all leaf directories that include only one occurrence of "modules":

```
find -regex '.*/modules\(/.*\|$\)' \! -regex '.*/modules/.*/modules\(/.*\|$\)' -type d -links 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name modules |\
awk '{gooddir[$1]=1}\
 END {\
    for(i in gooddir){\
        for(j in gooddir){\
            if(i!=j&&substr(i,0,length(j))==i)\
            {gooddir[i]=0;break}\
        }\
    }\
    for(i in gooddir){if(gooddir[i]==1){print i}}}'
```

try this?

Answer (score 0):

Your start

```
find . -name modules \! -exec sh -c 'find -name modules' \;
```

wasn't bad, it just needs some improvements.

```
find . -name modules \! -exec sh -c 'find {} -mindepth 1 -name modules|read' \; -print
```

- `{}` to search in the found modules directory, not in the top directory again
- `-mindepth 1` to search only under the found modules directory, not to find itself again
- `|read` to set the exit status (unfortunately, find doesn't do it) if no files are found
- `-print` to print the found directories